# Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a element - After version upgrade to 3.1.2

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Recently I have updated the wocommerce version to 3.1.2. But I am fetching problem when going to add variable product or editing variable product. It showing "`Uncaught Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a element.`" js error when selecting product attribute or variation.

```
Uncaught Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.
    at String.<anonymous> (ultimate-woocomposer-backend.min.js:1)
    at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui&load[]=-menu,wp-a11y,jquery-ui-autocomplete,underscore,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,media-models,plupload,jquery-ui-tooltip&ver=4.8.1:2)
    at d.prepareOpts (ultimate-woocomposer-backend.min.js:1)
    at d.prepareOpts (ultimate-woocomposer-backend.min.js:2)
    at d.init (ultimate-woocomposer-backend.min.js:1)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (ultimate-woocomposer-backend.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui&load[]=-menu,wp-a11y,jquery-ui-autocomplete,underscore,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,media-models,plupload,jquery-ui-tooltip&ver=4.8.1:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui&load[]=-menu,wp-a11y,jquery-ui-autocomplete,underscore,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,media-models,plupload,jquery-ui-tooltip&ver=4.8.1:2)
    at a.fn.init.a.fn.select2 (ultimate-woocomposer-backend.min.js:2)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (wc-enhanced-select.min.js:1)
```

See the screenshot below;

[image]

I have googled about this problem but no solution found, most of them are saying it is a bug (I am not sure).

Please help to resolve the problem.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I just want to share what I found and might can help someone else.
I got same issue with attribute section will stay in the loop, exactly same error I got in the console.

**Here's I try:**
Disable most common conflict plugin with this same error case I found online.

1. Disable Yoast SEO (which still not working for me, then just turn them back on)
2. Disable Visual composer, like page builder plugin, when I turn off **"Ultimate_VC_Addons"** this plugin, my attribute section is working agaian.
3. Might cause the conflict by theme, fall back to Wordpress default theme to check.
4. If cause by Advance custom field, you can check this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237329/acf-conflict-with-woo-commerce-attribute)
5. Check this [woocommerce doc](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/2.6.x-to-3.0.0-Developer-Migration-Notes#select2-version-4) if none of this help.