# ACF conflict with Woo-commerce attribute

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, advanced-custom-fields

I can't add attributes to products in woocommerce. It shows this error.

> select2.js:934 Uncaught Error: Option ‘ajax’ is not allowed for
>   Select2 when attached to a  element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a Conflict with WooCommerce and select2.js.
this error shows beacause woocommerce is updated i think this will solve your problem.

```
add_action('init', function() { define('SELECT2_NOCONFLICT', true); }, 1);
 function my_acf_init()
{
 acf_update_setting('select2_version', 4);
}
add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
```

Comment: if you got any other way to do this please post it here

Comment: i know this comment is not needed but it may get me a badge